# Using XML in Java as language manager

Tags: java, internationalization, translation

So, I'd like to create a bilingual program. From what I have heard, xml files are way to go...

I couldn't really find anything useful with Google (when you enter Java in Google it sees the word "language" only as in "programming", instead of desired "spoken"), so if any of you could direct me to some tutorial page which explains this topic further, or even show it to me here (It can be that complicated, can it?), I'd be very grateful.

If xml is way to go, that is! If any of you have any better suggestions, I'm listening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML could be the way to go, but the usual approach to ***internationalise*** your Java applications is using [`ResourceBundles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). When asking Google the right keywords are: **Java i18n** or **Java Internationalization**.

There is a [basic java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html) that can get you started with i18n. If you are writing a web application then you should check the documentation of your specific framework.

Answer (score 1):

Java has a built in internationalization system that uses properties files.

[Java Internationalization API Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html)